# Entering HTML text into an iframe

Tags: html, iframe, video, text

Is it possible to add "sub-text" to an iframe? For example I have the following code...

```
<iframe class="musicsamples" width="80%" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/apkRBANIKxc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

    <iframe class="musicsamples" width="80%" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/h7ArUgxtlJs" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

And I want to be able to add some text beneath that explains in detail the video etc, but whenever I've used a simple

tag within or just outside of the iframe, it treats it as if the iframe isn't present and the text always appears at the top of the page instead of beneath the iframe. Maybe I need to embed this video in some other way other than an iframe in order to be able to use text along with it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what isn't working for you, maybe your CSS is messing it up?

I was able to use the iframes of the videos and add a little description to them. Here is a sample, it's also on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asub2/)

```
<div>
    <iframe class="musicsamples" width="80%" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/apkRBANIKxc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <p>Pharoahe Monch Simon Says (Avicii Remix)</p>
</div>

<div>
    <iframe class="musicsamples" width="80%" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/h7ArUgxtlJs" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <p>deadmau5 feat. Rob Swire - Ghosts N Stuff</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I ended up figuring it out (I've never used jsFiddle before but that definitely helps out. I ended up finding that my class .musicsamples was floated to the left causing all text to appear at the top unformatted. Thanks janka!